# не работает clone repository

Tags: android, android-studio

Пытаюсь клонировать репозиторий путём [file - new - project from vercion control - git], внизу выскакивает загрузка на пол секунды и ничего не происходит. То же самое пытаюсь сделать через окно "Welcome to Android Studio", путём [Check out project from Version Control - git] и результат таков же. Помогите решить проблему

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Снизу в **Android Studio** есть терминал “Terminal”.

Введите следующие команду:

- **git clone [ssh link to repository]**

Пример: git clone git@github.com:elsemTim/android-kotlin-bus_schedule.git

Пример где найти ssh ссылку на github. 
[image: пример где найти ssh ссылку на github]

Update: Убрал команду **git init**, т.к. **git clone** уже включает в себя ее.